# replacement wood threshold insert for metal door

Tags: doors

I have some late 70's doors and one is missing a threshold insert (the adjustable wood kind), anybody know of where one could by just the "wood strip" that goes in and screws down (there seems to also be a small metal strip that sticks up into the middle of the wood, though you can't see it)?[image]  The brown strip down the middle here:

[image]

They have about 4 screws that go down into them?

Comment: And yet one neighbors door, exactly the same make, has a "metal" strip that appears to be adjustable height. Same door style (the old all thick'ish metal doors)...weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an "adjustable height" threshold, whereas the "strip" can be raised and lowered using the large screws seen in your picture. Unfortunately, there are many manufacturers (both foreign and domestic, long gone and still in business) and the parts are not interchangeable even if you managed to find a similar item.

You could try [this website](http://www.mdteam.com/index.php/products/thresholds), a common U.S. manufacturer. Unfortunately, I think we will be seeing a post not long from now that asks something like "how do I replace this entire threshold?"

Comment: yeah, wish I knew how to tell "make and model" from an ancient steel door without stickers :) thanks for your answer.  It seems like these used to be super common but now the insert just isn't sold anymore anywhere. There are some replacement wood inserts for "newer" doors but seemingly not this kind. Sigh. I think I'll try an MD 43336 "door sweep with fins" and see if that works enough to overcome the absence of the threshold insert...

Comment: (as an update, the door sweep would have worked but I couldn't get the old sweep off, so ended up just using an "under door draft stopper" style. Sigh.)

Answer (score 2):

I second Jimmy Fix-it's answer. I had the same problem and spent hours furiously trying to figure out what to do about what I assumed was a common problem. For your situation (or others in the future, since this was 2 years ago..) it looks like you could have easily replaced the entire threshold. For cases like mine, where the threshold extends far beyond the door frame for decorative purposes, it's far easier to just replace the wood insert. 
Cut yourself a piece of the correct dimensions from scrap wood and fasten it down however you please. Saves a lot of frustration trying to find the correct matching replacement part, if you have wood threshold inserts like many homes have. Sanding to round the edges a bit is recommended.

Comment: I like this.  Maybe sand it down to the desired size, or add shims if it's too small? :)

Comment: @rogerdpack I'd suggest starting with a slightly oversized piece and cutting/sanding/planing it down to size. That would be _far_ easier than attempting to shim it, especially if you're shimming up from the bottom. Maybe one of your neighbors is a wood worker who would be willing to do a bit of work for you in exchange for a bit of cash/beverage/etc.

Comment: Another idea I had would be to add washers to normal machine screws (between the very bottom and the wood).  LOL

Answer (score 2):

Too late for the original poster, but for others who find this with the same issue - looks like someone has them now:

https://betterdoor.com/shop/exterior-door-sills-thresholds-replacement-parts/endura-composite-z-series-adjustable-cap/

https://betterdoor.com/shop/exterior-door-sills-thresholds-replacement-parts/endura-oak-adjustable-cap/

Answer (score 0):

Home Depot does [stock](https://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-3-ft-x-5-5-8-in-x-1-1-8-in-Oak-Aluminum-Threshold-78600/100124956) some "adjustable height" thresholds.  You might be able to buy one and rip out its insert and re-use.  Not clear if it would fit right...

[image: for sale]

and apparently these things are called "sill caps".